# Python Sphinx autosummary rendering of parameters like numpy

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

### Problem

I am using Sphinx and the autosummary extension to document my python 3 project with numpy style docstring.

**Current rendering**

This is my current rendering. The red box shows the current layout for parameters and returns.

[image: current rendering]

**Desired rendering**

I would like to change the layout of parameters and returns like numpy, shown in desired rendering example below, so that parameter name and type is in one line, and the description is indented in another line.

[image: desired rendering example]

How do I achieve that? (Looking into numpy, scipy, and pandas docs, I couldn't find what special thing did they do to change the rendering.)

### Numpy stype docstring

The docstring in the code is:

```py
def modified_main(raw_img_path, ground_truth_img_path, ground_truth_count=None, sort=True):
    """
    Computes deviation of thresholded images using different methods
    compared to user input ground truth image.

    Parameters
    ----------
    raw_img_path : str
        Path of raw image.
    ground_truth_img_path : str
        Path of ground truth image.
    ground_truth_count : int, optional
        User input ground truth cell count.
    sort : bool, optional
        Sort the deviation by majority vote.

    Returns
    -------
    optimal_method : str
        Optimal threshold method.
    optimal_threshold : float
        Threshold given by optimal threshold method.

    """
    pass
```

### Sphinx config

I have included extensions needed for autosummary in the `conf.py` file:

```py
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc',
              'sphinx.ext.napoleon',
              'sphinx.ext.autosummary']
autosummary_generate = True
html_theme = 'pydata_sphinx_theme'
```

The use of autosummary is shown here:

```
.. currentmodule:: modified

.. autosummary::
   :toctree: api/

   modified_main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution by really digging into the numpydoc documentation. In the `extension` variable in `conf.py`, change the element `sphinx.ext.napoleon` to `numpydoc`. The changed variable now looks like

```py
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc',
              'numpydoc',
              'sphinx.ext.autosummary']
```

The rendering becomes

[image]

where the red box gives desired rendering like that of numpy.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue is that your formatting of reST in your docstring is not similar to that of [`empty`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/623bc1fae1d47df24e7f1e29321d0c0ba2771ce0/numpy/matlib.py#L24).

```
def empty(shape, dtype=None, order='C'):
    """Return a new matrix of given shape and type, without initializing entries.

    Parameters
    ----------
    shape : int or tuple of int
        Shape of the empty matrix.
    dtype : data-type, optional
        Desired output data-type.
    order : {'C', 'F'}, optional
        Whether to store multi-dimensional data in row-major
        (C-style) or column-major (Fortran-style) order in
        memory.

    See Also
    --------
    empty_like, zeros

    .. snip

    """
```

You did not include an example of your docstring, so I cannot be absolutely certain.  Please edit your question to include your docstring.

Comment: Even with reST formatting in the docstring that is consistent with that in numpy doc (updated above), the rendering did not change.